# Valid json giving json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter

Tags: python, json

I’m learning about how to handle json using python but it is giving me an error.

Here's my code

```
import json
people_string = """
{
"people": [
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "phone": 666-625-7263,
        "emails": ["john.smith@fakemail.com","johnsmith@workmail.com"],
        "has_license": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phone": 666-625-7263,
        "emails": null,
        "has_license": true 
    }
  ]
} 
"""
data = json.loads(people_string)
```

I’m getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Tanishq/Desktop/Tanishq-imp/python tutorials/json-35.py", line 20, in <module>
    data = json.loads(people_string) #https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders
  File "C:\Users\Tanishq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Tanishq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Tanishq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 6 column 21 (char 71)
```

Comment: ``phone`` field is invalid, it should be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* where to look.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the json literal string, you defined the pair `phone` incorrectly...

You should do

```
....
    "phone": "666-625-7263",
....
```

I mean, the number must be between "" because it is a string, not a number (because of the **-** symbols)

Answer (score 1):

wrap the `phone` value with `double quote` (`" "`)

```
import json
people_string = '''
{
"people": [
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "phone": "666-625-7263",
        "emails": ["john.smith@fakemail.com","johnsmith@workmail.com"],
        "has_license": false
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Doe",
        "phone": "666-625-7263",
        "emails": null,
        "has_license": true 
    }
  ]
}'''
data = json.loads(people_string)
```